# How do I push an object to an array x amount of times with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

If `array = [1,2,3,4,5]`, how can I push the number `6`, `x` amount of times to the `array`.

```
array.push(6) * x
```

When I run something like that it returns the entire array that was pushed `6`, `x` amount of times. Putting *parentheses* around the `push * x` makes my code invalid, any suggestions?

Example:

```
array.push(6) "2 times" => [1,2,3,4,5,6,6]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, You can using [`Array#fill`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-fill) method.

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
array.fill(12, array.size, 4)
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 12, 12, 12]
```

*Explanation*

> Suppose you have an array `a = [1,2,3]`. Now `a.size` will give you `3`, where last index is `2`. So, when you are using `a.size` with `#fill`, then you are telling to start pushing *object* from `3` to some `n` number of times.

Comment: Hi @Arup, thanks for the quick response. is there a way to use the fill method without the last object in the array getting destroyed?

Comment: You don't want to modify the _original_ array ?

Comment: @Lasonic Using `#fill` you can _fill_ where ever you want. Your example was showing to _push_ the object into the array _some number of times_. Thus I used `-1`. Check the documentation.

Comment: @Arup, my goal here is to not modify the original array, just append whatever I want to the end of it. When you started at -1, the object 5 in your array was taken out and replaced with the 4 12's you filled in. Is there a way to keep both?

Comment: @Lasonic Done.. Sorry. That's my mistake

Comment: +1, I never used `fill`, what `array.size` actually does here?

Comment: @Surya Suppose you have an array `a = [1,2,3]`. Now `a.size` will give you `3`, where last index is `2`. So, when you are using `a.size` with `#fill`, then you are telling to start pushing objects from `3` to some `n` number of times.. Hope that's clear. :-)

Comment: Great. Why don't you add this to your answer, I'm sure that'll help others as well. :)

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
irb(main):002:0> a += [6] * 2
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]
```

Alternatively:

```
irb(main):003:0> a.concat([8] * 3)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this instead.. much cleaner to read and understand

`arr.concat([3]*4)`

so

`[1,2]`

will become

`[1,2,3,3,3,3]`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a range for this

```
(0..5).each{|i| array << 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array - stores a collection of variables
x - the number of times you want to push a number
n - the number you are pushing to the array    
def push(array, x, n)
  x.times{array.push(n)}
  return array
end
```

Comment: Please provide some comments as to how this code solves the problem above.